# What might be causing "Failed to open ALSA device" errors when using a DAC board?

Tags: audio-playback

## The equipment

I'm using:

- Raspberry Pi Zero W
- [Allo BOSS DAC board](https://www.allo.com/sparky/boss-dac.html)
- [Volumio](https://volumio.org) music player software
- official Raspberry Pi PSU

I've tried more than one official Raspberry Pi PSU as well as other PSUs.

## The problem

After a few days without issue, attempts to play audio will produce no sound (though the software seems to think it is playing) and an error is reported in the Volumio interface:

```
Error
Failed to open "alsa" [alsa]; Failed to open ALSA device "hw:1,0": 
No such file or directory
```

Everything else in all other respects appears to work as expected.

In order to get it working again, the unit needs to be powered down (not just restarted - the power needs to be disconnected completely) and after restarting, it will once again work for a few days. This almost always works.

## Further information

Speculation on the Volumio forums suggest that this is related to a power issue, and that would make sense to me - possibly the DAC board enters a fault state and needs to be powered down before it will work again.

When the unit is in its working state, the `sudo i2cdetect -y 1` and `aplay -l` commands have the following output:

```
~$ sudo i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --                         

$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 7/7
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: BossDAC [BossDAC], device 0: Boss DAC HiFi [Master] pcm512x-hifi-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

When in the fault state, the output is:

```
$ sudo i2cdetect -y 1
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --                         

$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 7/7
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out the solution to this? Having a similar issue with my Hifiberry DAC